# What are the tools available for data replication on oracle and/or db2?

Tags: oracle, db2, database-replication

I just need to know the name of the tools in order to establish a start line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for LUW has [SQL Replication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.sqltutorial.doc/topics/iiyrstutcoverview.html) and [High Availability Disaster Recovery](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006354.html) clustering.

Answer (score 1):

Check [goldengate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10803/config_gg.htm#HABPT5286) solution from Oracle.